# Canvas HTML5 Performance - Chrome significantly slower than Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, html5-canvas

I have written a game using HTML5 and Javascript. The game can be played at www.be-sw.com/game/2. I don't think posting the code here will be helpful as it is lengthy. It uses two loops; a game logic loop and a request animation frame loop and I don't think there's anything particularly complex in the logic.

Until recently it worked at the same speed on Chrome, IE and Firefox on all computers where it was tested.

However, it has suddenly started performing differently on Chrome v38 on some computers - Chrome slows the entire game to 10% of it's speed so the game becomes extremely slow to play. I can't identify any potential causes of this variation - it seems random whether Chrome plays it slow or normal on a computer. On all computers it works fine on FF and IE.

On the computers where the issue occurs, using Chrome's profiler, I can see that the issue is not CPU usage it only uses 2-3% of CPU at most) and there is normally a significant percent idle. At times Program uses 20-30% but there is still always idle CPU.

Any suggestions as to what might be causing this / how I can approach resolving it?

Comment: How can we possibly debug your code if we can't see it? We could answer with generic "Look at X" suggestions, but that won't result in a good answer.

Comment: You mention Chrome 38 - is this the problem?  Is it always on 38 that it's slow?  Perhaps [this is related](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=421235)?

Comment: Or more specifically [this one](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422000)

Comment: Thanks James - it looks like it might be related to the second issue you've found. Adding the --disable-gpu-vsync flag improves the performance somewhat.

It works perfectly fine on Chrome 38 on other computers but I think there might be a connection as I can't replicate the issue on older versions of Chrome.

Comment: Are they all windows PCs?  It specifically mentions it's chrome 38 on windows that's at fault

Comment: Yes - I've tested it on 4 computers. Two computers with Windows 8 are slow, two with Windows 7 are fine. Could that really be the cause though?

If it might be helpful - am happy to post the source code but I'm not expecting anyone to read through 2,000 lines.

Comment: If Chrome 37 is fine, it would certainly seem to be an issue with 38, and they clearly have at least one problem with canvas performance in 38

Comment: @JamesThorpe, why don't you post an answer with that info?  Looks very relevant, to say the least.

Comment: It didn't feel like an answer, but ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Chrome v38 has [introduced at least one](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422000) issue with `canvas` performance.  If Chrome 37 continues to perform normally, I'd put it down to a Chrome bug/regression.

Comment: Thanks - though the issue is not an exact match, based on the similarities it may be the cause. I don't think I'll get a better answer - apologies for not the greatest of questions.